# How to build Visual Studio project under Gradle?

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio, gradle

I'm only couple days in Gradle, so please don't be mad if I don't understand something.

I have C++ project that I can build from VS 2015 or command line like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>devenv q:\VCPROJ\SystemAl.sln
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>MSBuild q:\VCPROJ\SystemAl.sln
```

But I need to build this project project under Gradle.
So, I've googled this - https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.ide.visualstudio.VisualStudioProject.html
And I wrote build.gradle like this:

```
apply plugin: "visual-studio"
model {
visualStudio {
    projects.all {
        projectFile.location = projectFile.location =     "q:/VCPROJ/SystemAl.vcxproj"
        projectFile.withXml {
            asNode().appendNode('PropertyGroup', [Label: 'Custom'])
                    .appendNode('ProjectDetails', "Project is named SystemAl")
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I build it with command:

```
gradle build
```

But nothing happening, Gradle project is built success, but VS  projects isn't built.
What I'm doing wrong? How can I build VS project under Gradle?

Answer (score 5):

The builtin support for visual studio will generate project files, but won't parse them.

In your case you can give a try to [gradle-msbuild-plugin](https://github.com/Ullink/gradle-msbuild-plugin) which should work, although it's been primarly tested with C#/F# projects:

```
plugins {
  id "com.ullink.msbuild" version "2.10"
}

msbuild {
  solutionFile = 'q:\\VCPROJ\\SystemAl.sln'
  projectName = 'SystemAl'
}
```

Then `gradle msbuild`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by Gluck, Visual Studio 2015 support was just added within the past few weeks.  The latest Gradle release, 3.2.1, still doesn't support VS2015, but the latest [nightly builds](https://gradle.org/gradle-nightly-build/) do.  You can experiment with these, but it's probably best to wait for whatever build comes next that includes this support.